# Swift loop through subviews and get the name for if condition

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a loop like so:

```
for views in webview.scrollView.subviews
        {
            if(views.isKindOfClass(UIImageView))
            {
            }
        }
```

inside the isKindOfClass condition, I would like to get the UIImageView image name and do another condition to see if the UIImageView is a certain image name. Something like this:

```
for views in webview.scrollView.subviews
        {
            if(views.isKindOfClass(UIImageView))
            {
                //if image name is equal to stamp.png
            }
        }
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible.
You may want use accessibilityIdentifier instead:

```
for view in webview.scrollView.subviews {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        if imageView.accessibilityIdentifier == "yourImageID" {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can define accessibility identifier for the UIImageView in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 4):

A `UIImageView` contains a `UIImage` and a `UIImage` doesn't have a name property; it is just an image. It may have come from a file with a name or it may not, but essentially it is just a series of bytes that represent an image.

So, you cannot determine the "name" of an image contained in a `UIImageView`